# speed difference dblinq results vs sql query in prompt

Tags: c#, join, dblinq

I've setup a database to be used with dblinq.

```
CREATE TABLE 'quotes' (                                                                                                      
      'DBDate' int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                         
      'TickerID' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                      
      'Open' double(12,4) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
      'High' double(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                          
      'Low' double(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                           
      'Close' double(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                         
      'AdjClose' double(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                      
      'Volume' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                        
      PRIMARY KEY ('TickerID','DBDate'),                                                                                         
      CONSTRAINT 'quotes_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('TickerID') REFERENCES 'tickers' ('TickerID') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

the above is the mysql table schedule 
The MySQL server is on a different machine. 
When I run this mysql query on my test machine (so not the same machine as the server)

> SELECT a.*, b.* FROM quotes a INNER JOIN quotes b ON a.DBDate =
>   b.DBDate AND a.TickerID=956 and b.TickerID=957 order by a.dbdate asc;

I'll get an output as expected:
2934 rows in set (0.03 sec)

but when I want to get the same result in my C# envirement using DBLinq like this:

```
var tradeAbleA = (from a in _db.Quotes where a.TickerID == 956 select a);
var tradeAbleB = (from a in _db.Quotes where a.TickerID == 957 select a);
var myDataSet = (from a in tradeAbleA.AsEnumerable() join b in tradeAbleB.AsEnumerable() on a.DbdAte equals b.DbdAte orderby a.DbdAte ascending select new { a, b }).ToList();
```

it takes over a second to get the list filled. This is way too long. How can I speed this up? (I need it in a list)
regards,

Matthijs

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your Sql translate to the following linq?

```
var myDataSet = (from a in _db.Quotes 
    join b in db.Quotes on a.DbdAte equals a.DbdAte 
    where a.TickerID == 956 && b.TickerID == 957 
    orderby a.DbdAte ascending select new { a, b }).ToList();
```

In your current version, you create the query for a and b seperately, and by calling `.AsEnumerable()` on them in the 3rd of your linq expressions you force them to be evaluated.  You move the results in memory, which then Linq to Objects joins for you (which can be expensive).  You then order the remaining items in memory.

The above should allow you to pass all these steps through to the query provider which tend to be *much* faster.

Comment: The funny thing is that I actually had a linq query like you propose, but I got an error message that the types of a and b did not match (or something like that. I'll post the exact message tomorrow.). That's why i split it up in two separate queries and join them in the third. I'll test your query tomorrow and let you know what the problem is (if any). Thanks for the respond.

Comment: ok, I tested your query on my laptop. When I use my split method, it takes about 750 ms to get it in a list (list is half the size of the previous test and is 1358 rows long). But when I use the query as you suggest, it takes about 3 minutes and 23 seconds and returns 2763418 rows instead. It doesn't properly take care of the a.DbdAte equals b.DbdAte. I don't see why...any suggestions?

Comment: @user369122 That sounds a little off... what type is DbdAte?  Hard to tell with the capitals but I was assuming it was a date?

Comment: it's uint (unsigned integer). But still, why is the "normal" join so much slower...and why does it return that much rows? there is something off with the join and equals isn't it?

Comment: I've read it over and over, albeit with a beer or two in me now, and can't see how your results would come out like that.  Your 3 expressions should generate 2 database queries, and the rest of the operations in memory whereas mine should generate 1 database query and no real in-memory work.  Are you sure you've typed it all out correctly? Definitely not using `AsEnumerable()` any more?

Comment: although I had a drink as well (cheers by the way ;-)), I copied your code into my editor. I only changed a.DbdAte equals a.DbdAte to a.DbdAte equals b.DbdAte and changed the ID numbers. But that't it... this is the code I tested: 

var myDataSet2 = (from a in _db.Quotes
                              join b in _db.Quotes on a.DbdAte equals b.DbdAte
                              where a.TickerID == 12 && b.TickerID == 13
                              orderby a.DbdAte ascending
                              select new { a, b }).ToList();

I'll test some more in the morning. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added this issue to the DBLinq forum. Hopefully they know why this is happening. http://groups.google.com/group/dblinq-bugs/browse_thread/thread/9784ba43a5fe5132

Comment: I just did another test and joint the table with another table like this: 
var dataset2 = (from x in _db.Quotes
                           join y in _db.Tickers
                           on x.TickerID equals y.TickerID
                           where x.TickerID == 956
                           select new { x, y }).ToList();

Works fine. Fast even. The problem seems to be with a join on the same table.